# How to return value when Realm transaction success?

Tags: android, transactions, realm

I have this method, i want return value when the transaction complete, but i cant. This's my code

```
public List<Group> getConversations() {

        final RealmResults<Group> conversations;

        try {

            mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            mRealm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {

                    RealmResults<Group> conversations = realm.where(Group.class).findAllSorted("time", Sort.DESCENDING);
                    cursorConversation(conversations);
                }
            }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                   //return conversation
                }
            });
        }

return null;

    }
```

What should i do ?

Comment: That wouldn't even work. You'd get an illegal thread access exception.

Comment: What are you doing in `cursorConversation(..)`?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what are you doing in `cursorConversation(..)` but you can use the same method on returned values from Realm.

give a try

```
public List<Group> getConversations() {

    try (Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {

        return realm.copyFromRealm(realm.where(Group.class).findAllSorted("time", Sort.DESCENDING));
    }

}
```

Comment: _Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted._

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to run a transaction for getting the conversations. You can run your query on the realm db and add a change listener to the result. When the query completes, it'll call that change listener with the `RealmResults<Converstaion>`, Check this [link](https://www.realm.io/docs/java/5.1.0/api/io/realm/realmquery#findAllAsync--) for more.

Something like

```
public void listenToConversations(RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Conversation>> listener) {
     RealmResults<Conversations> conversations = realm.where(Group.class).sort("time", Sort.DESCENDING).findAllAsync();
     conversations.addChangeListener(listener);
}
```

where listener is something like

```
listener = new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Conversations>>() {
           \@Override
           public void onChange(RealmResults<Conversations> conversations) {
               // React to change
           }
       }
```

You'll also need to remove listener to avoid any memory leaks.